# Recording from radio streaming xcode 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4, audio-recording

I'm building an iPhone app which play some radio over internet ..

I want to make user able to record audio from my application to the radio channel he wants ..

what framework I must use .. and what code for implementation please ?

all Regards

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to directly capture from the "audio bus". You can either capture the audio via the internal microphone or headset microphone, but that's it. If you are rendering the audio, you could obviously also write that audio out to a file as well at the same time. That's pretty much your only option.

Comment: but there are some apps in the store which record from radio stream ..how did they do it ???